# i need help for solving this , im not able to understand the error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm getting this these days .but i'm not able to solve this while running a server

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/056Ct.png)

Comment: Please read this [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you because we need the textual version (not an image) of the error, the code that has generated the error, and a [mcve] in order to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you've imported from `django.contib`, which is incorrect. It should be `django.contrib` (notice the missing `r` in `contib`).